# No reconoce el comando webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

tengo el inconveniente de que al momento de querer ejecutar el comando "webpack" para generar la carpeta de produccion me lanza un error. He intentado borrando el cache, usando npm install -g webpack-dev-server ademas de npm install -g webpack y aun asi no logro que funcione el comando, la unica manera es utilizando npm run build. El npm start funciona sin problema alguno. Hay alguna manera de solucionar ese inconveniente? Saludos.

Aqui el codigo de webpack.config

{

```
 test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        esModule: false,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },

    new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets/'},
                ],
            }),
```

[image: Aqui el error]

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que estas escribiendo:

```
webpack
```

cuando debería ser:

```
npm webpack
```

para que funcione bien debes posicionarte en la misma carpeta base de tu proyecto, (la misma que tiene el package.json) y escribir este comando.
especificamente te falla porque te falta anteponer el comando npm.
en los scripts de tu package.json el script **npm run build** que tienes, ya por el mero hecho de escribir **npm run**, ya agrega el comando npm por eso ves que tu script build en el package json solo dice "webpack". pero si tu quieres hacerlo directo sin el npm run, debes escribir **npm webpack**

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/230095)

Comment: listo, corregido

Answer (score 0):

Intentaré con lo que me has dicho, es que tenía la duda, ya que he visto a personas que con solo escribir el comando webpack, les genera el build de producción.

Si escribo npm webpack lo que hace es abrir un menú de ayuda con varios comandos, pero como dices intentaré agregar el npm webpack directo al Json, Saludos!